# For positive real numbers $a,b,c$ prove that $ a^4 + b^4 + c^4 \ge abc(a+b+c)$

Tags: inequality

For positive reals $a,b,c$ prove that $$ a^4+b^4+c^4 \ge abc(a+b+c). $$
I tried to pls around trying to reorganize to get AM-GM but i couldn't 
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You could take a look at the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality). Alternately, there is probably a Cauchy-Schwartz in there somewhere.

Comment: How can you say there is cauchy in there... What cues lead you to think that

Comment: There is always a CS hiding in any inequality. Especially the symmetric ones. That's something I picked up from my IMO days. I never got good at inequalities, but I did pick up that CS was _important_.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1819975/42969.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480000/using-arithmetic-meangeometric-mean

Comment: I have added an answer based on the convexity of $x^4$ here at the duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480000/using-arithmetic-meangeometric-mean/3353323#3353323

Comment: Muirhead: $(4,0,0)\gg(2,1,1)$.

Answer (score 5):

By AM_GM we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{2a^4+b^4+c^4}{4} & \geq a^2bc\\
\frac{2b^4+a^4+c^4}{4} & \geq b^2ac\\
\frac{2c^4+b^4+a^4}{4} & \geq c^2ab
\end{align*}
Now add these to get your inequality.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\frac{a^4+a^4+b^4+c^4}{4}\geq abca \\
\frac{a^4+b^4+b^4+c^4}{4}\geq abcb \\
\frac{a^4+c^4+b^4+c^4}{4}\geq abcc \\$$

Answer (score 1):

Why should the mean inequalities not work? Geometric mean vs. mean of power 4
$$
abc\le\left(\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}3\right)^{\frac34}
$$and arithmetic mean vs. mean of power 4$$
\frac{a+b+c}3\le\left(\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}3\right)^{\frac14}
$$
implies
$$
\frac{abc(a+b+c)}3\le \frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}3.
$$

Comment: How do you conclude the second inequality from the first one?

Comment: I am unable to understand the second line

Comment: @MostafaAyaz : You don't. The mean inequality chain is geometric mean $\le$ arithmetic mean $\le$ quadratic mean $\le$ cubic mean $\le$ quartic mean etc.

Comment: @TamaghnaChaudhuri : This is the mean inequality for the 4th degree power function. In general, for any convex function $f$ you get the Jensen inequality $f(\frac{x_1+...+x_n}n)\le\frac{f(x_1)+...+f(x_n)}n$. Here use $f(x)=x^4$ for the second inequality. Or apply the inequality for arithmetic and quadratic mean twice.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
&(x^2-y^2)^2+(y^2-z^2)^2+(z^2-x^2)^2 \\&+2(z^2-xy)^2 +2(x^2-yz)^2+2(y^2-zx)^2\geq 0
\end{eqnarray*}
now divide by $4$ and rearrange.